# Abort (core dumped) when freeing array created with calloc

Tags: c, free, calloc

This

```
#include <stdlib.h> // test.c

int main()
{
    double *arr = (double*) calloc(1000, sizeof(arr));
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        arr[i] = 1; 
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled as

```
gcc test.c -std=c99 -o test
```

produces the output `Aborted (core dumped)` when run on Cygwin as `./test.exe`.

The program exits fine when I declare `int *arr` (even while keeping the `(double *)` cast),  or when I update `arr[0]` instead of `arr[i]`. What gives?

Comment: lol thanks for all the downvotes. Apparently I shouldn't turn to SO when stumped with something stupid :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
double *arr = (double*) calloc(1000, sizeof(arr));
```

to

```
double *arr = (double*) calloc(1000, sizeof(double));
```

UPDATE:

`sizeof(double)` and `sizeof(pointer)` depends on architecture. In your case they are different.

Comment: I wanted to say this too, but its still interesting why this gets so wrong, sizeof(double pointer) != sizeof(double) ?

Comment: Ahh yes, that, or `sizeof(*arr)`... Missed the damn asterisk!

Comment: @Gabriel pointers may not be size of double. No matter what they are pointing at, the size of pointers is always the same (and depend on the architecture)

Comment: @wrongusername it would be nice if you accepted the answer

Comment: @zoska 3 minutes to go before I can accept the answer

Comment: @zoska, pointers to different types may be different sizes. I have used such a system.

Comment: @MattMcNabb then how does `void *` work on this system?

Comment: `void *` is the largest type, because other object pointer types have to be convertible to `void *`. This system had `void *` as 3 bytes, and some other pointers were 2 bytes. The third byte of the `void *` indicated what sort of pointer had been converted.